# How can I Print using FlexPrintJob in Landscape?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, mxml

How can I print a flex component in landscape orientation using FlexPrintJob?

Answer (score 1):

FlexPrintJob doesn't have an orientation property. There is a case reported in Flex Bug and Management System [SDK-11211](http://bugs.adobe.com/jira/browse/SDK-11211). There is [workaround](http://jessewarden.com/2008/09/forcing-landscape-printing-in-flex-2-3.html?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3a%20jessewarden%20%28Flex%20and%20Flash%20Developer%20-%20Jesse%20Warden%20dot%20Kizz-ohm%29) for this but it's not very effective. If someone knows better solution for this, I would be very interested seeing it.

Comment: i find solution myself :))) i put FlexPrintJob class, add this line "printJob.orientation = "landscape";" to addObject class and rewrite all to my own print class. it`s working 100% ....

Answer (score 0):

You can rotate the component (component.rotation = 90) then print and rotate it again.